# Error in Wordpress - Insert URL into a post

Tags: wordpress, url, blogs

I have a Wordpress blog and I have a problem with it since last year. When I try to add a link to an entry, the dialog box appears strangely. It can be seen in the attached image.

Does anyone know what could be happening?

Thanks!

http://prntscr.com/33rip8

P.D: I have some plugins installed, could be the reason?

Comment: Try disabling the plugins and see if it works, if it does then enable them one by one until you find the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version are you currently running?

It will most likely be a plugin problem. If you go through each plugin un-activating it, retesting if the bug appears and if not then move onto the next plugin.

Some plugins may have new or depreciated functions, and looking at your screenshot, it does look like your running quite an old version of WordPress.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and I found that it was a plugin named "Links error reporting".Problem solved. Thanks again!